# React. Login and out

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have added auth0 to my app which seems to be working when it comes to logging in. What i would like to know is how do i add a state to the class then pass the props from there and pass the state as a prop, so that firstly it will change the button text from Sign In to Sign Out and have the functionality to logout[image]

From what i understand i need to use isAuthenticated && on the button to allow it to log out + logout on the onClick but im unsure how to execute it in this situation

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up like this

```
const { loginWithRedirect, logout} = useAuth0();

{!isAuthenticated ? (
  <button onClick={() =>loginWithRedirect()}>Sign In</button>
) : (
  <button onClick={() =>logout({returnTo: window.location.origin)}>Sign Out</button>
)}
```